# Show that the Range of the multiplication operator $M_a$ is dense in $L_p (\Omega)$ provided that $a \neq 0$ a.e. in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: operator-theory, lp-spaces

Here, $1 \le p < \infty$

I thought that maybe - for $a \neq 0 $ a.e. in $\Omega$ - it is true, that

$$\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0 \subset \mathcal{R}(M_a)$$

And because $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0$ is dense in $L_p (\Omega)$, then this would mean that the range of $M_a$ is dense too in $L_p (\Omega)$

But I don't know if we can argue like that here.

The next step in that exercise would be to show that $\mathcal{R}(M_a) = L_p (\Omega)$, if there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $|a(x)| \ge c$ a.e. in $\Omega$

That's why I doubt my solution would be the right one here

Comment: @OliverDíaz I literally don't understand how the link you've posted should help me here. I simply don't understand the solution to that exercise

Comment: @OliverDíaz Just forget my attempt, apparently it doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out why the solution you've sent me should be the solution I'm looking for, and especially,, how it's working in the first place

Comment: @OliverDíaz Please, just forget about this approach. I really *need* the solution for at least the part, where $R(M_a) = L_p(\Omega)$ if there's a $c \ge 0$ such $|a(x)| \ge c$

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that $1\leq p<\infty$, If $M_a(L_p)$ is to be contained in $L_p$, then $a$ must be in $L_\infty$:
Suppose not. Then there are infinitely many sets in the sequence $E_n=\{n\leq a<n+1\}$ that have positive measure, say $E_{n_k}$ $k\leq n_k<n_{k+1}$. Choose  $A_{n_k}\subset E_{n_k}$ be positive and finite measure and define
$$g(x)=\sum_k\frac{1}{k\,(m(A_{n_k}))^{1/p}}\mathbb{1}_{A_{n_k}}$$
Then $g\in L_p$, however
$$\int|ag|^p\,dm=\sum_k\frac{1}{k^p m(A_{n_k})}\int_{A_{n_k}}|a|^p\,dm\geq\sum_k\mathbb{1}=\infty$$
Thus $a\in L_\infty$ and moreover,
$$\|M_af\|_p\leq\|a\|_\infty\|f\|_p$$

---

If $M_a(L_p)=L_p$,  then there is  $c>0$ such that $c<|a|\leq\|a\|_\infty$ (and vice versa).

I outline the prove here and leave the details to the OP

1. Show that $m(|a|=0)=0$. If that were not the case, choose $E\subset\{|a|=0\}$ with positive finite measure. Define $g=\mathbb{1}_E$. Clearly $g\in L_p$, but there is no $f\in L_p$ such that $M_af=g$.
2. W.l.g. assumee $|a|>0$. Then $M_a$ is one to one. As $M_a$ is onto, and application of the open map theorem implies that $M_a$ has a bounded inverse. Notice that the inverse of $M_a$ is $M_{1/a}$. Then $1/a\in L_\infty$ (why?).